# How can I .slidetoggle a div the .length of a string in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a label where if you hover over it, it should expand the length of the text inside. I would like to slide the div next to it the width of the label (depending on the length of the word). Here is the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5s69j/1/

I want to use the .length to slide the div next to it because I don't want to hardcode it.

I ultimately want to have the title div visible at all times if there is a label or not. If there IS a label then I want the title to be to the right of the label at all times. If there ISN'T a label then I don't want space before the title, which is why I'm not using margin.

Here I'm trying to set a hover function on the labels to slide the title the length of label. And I think that I need something to calculate the length of a string. Let me know if I'm missing something obvious.

```
$(function(){
    var stuff = $(".labels").length;
    $('.labels').hover(function{
      $(".title").slideToggle(stuff, function() {

  });
 });
});
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this, here is solution without js

HTML

```
<div class="labels">
    <div class="new"></div>
    <div class="firstlabel">label label</div>
</div>
<div class="title">title goes here</div>`

* {
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.labels {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 20px;
  color: #7cbf50;
  background-color: #7cbf50;
}
.firstlabel {
    white-space: nowrap;+
}

.labels:hover {
  max-width: 500px;
}
.labels:hover .firstlabel {
  color: #fff;
}
```

or see the following

http://jsfiddle.net/5s69j/8

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5s69j/6/) - let me know if you want anything changed. You just needed to have them `display: inline-block;` and remove the absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/5s69j/5/) Check this.

```
display:inline-block
```

Use the above. It ll solve your problem